# Why does my django postgres cursor query timeout after fetching all rows?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm working on migrating postgres data with django. I execute a raw sql query against one schema and use the django ORM to populate the target schema.  The raw query looks like this:

```
query = '''
    SELECT {columns}
    FROM tbl_one one
    INNER JOIN tbl_two two on two.one_id=one.id
    WHERE one.filter = '{filter}'
        AND two._created_at >= '{start_date} 00:00:00'
    ORDER BY two._created_at;
    '''.format(columns=', '.join(columns), filter=filter,
               start_date=start_date)

if connections['old_schema'].connection is None:
    cursor = connections['old_schema'].cursor()

with transaction.atomic(using='old_schema'):
    cursor.execute(query)
    while True:
        rows = cursor.fetchmany(1000)

        if not rows:
            break
        for row in rows:
            yield dict(zip(columns, row)))
```

However, on very long queries, the raw query barfs **after** yielding all the rows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/.virtualenvs/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 139, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
psycopg2.DatabaseError: SSL SYSCALL error: Connection timed out


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "~/.virtualenvs/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "~/.virtualenvs/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "~/.virtualenvs/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "~/.virtualenvs/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "~/app/management/commands/migrate_cass_data.py", line 166, in handle
    for pg in self.get_from_postgres(filter, start_date):
  File "~/app/management/commands/migrate_cass_data.py", line 235, in get_from_postgres
    yield dict(zip(columns, row)))
  File "~/.virtualenvs/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 316, in __exit__
    connection.commit()
  File "~/.virtualenvs/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 171, in commit
    self._commit()
  File "~/.virtualenvs/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 139, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
  File "~/.virtualenvs/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "~/.virtualenvs/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 549, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "~/.virtualenvs/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 139, in _commit
    return self.connection.commit()
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: SSL SYSCALL error: Connection timed out
```

Again, when the query result is smaller, it works fine. When the result is large, the query seems to return all of the results, but it doesn't seem to wrap up cleanly.  Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer for this issue?  I'm getting the same error on any long operation I attempt.

Comment: I did not.  The postgres server is in GCE and I'm wondering if GCE networking is closing the connection.